# PSU type on HP z440

Tags: power-supply

I have a HP Z440 to which I wish to acquire a new Power Supply Unit. According to the specs [here](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04400038.pdf) and the tag on the actual PSU, the unit has the power supply listed [here](http://www.plugloadsolutions.com/psu_reports/HEWLETT%20PACKARD_719795-001_700W_ECOS%203915_Report.pdf).

I wish to change this PSU with a third party one (with higher specs), but given the peculiar form of the current PSU, I don't know what I should be looking for.

Could anybody tell me what PSU form factor would fit the case? I am not sure if an ATX PSU would match, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Brand name workstations tend to use non-ATX form factors for their PSUs. One of the annoyances that puts me off buying them. Potentially if you wanted to do some DIY, you could get something to fit.